# How to move specific files to new folder in java

Tags: java, file, move

I want to move 4 files having file name as FGA to new folder

```
public void delete(String DirectoryName) {
         String dir = DirectoryName;

         File file = new File(dir);

         boolean recursive = true;

         Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(file, null, recursive);

         for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                File file1 = (File) iterator.next();
                if (file1.getName().contains("FGA_"))
                      file1.delete();
                else if (file1.getName().contains("UPP_"))
                      file1.delete();

         }
         System.out.println("Files deleted");
   }
```

Comment: before deleting i want to move file to new folder.. how should be done..

Comment: [`Files.move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...))

Answer (score 2):

I do see you are using [commons.apache.org](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) library, so you can use `moveFile` from there

```
public static void moveFile(File srcFile,
        File destFile)
                 throws IOException
```

or from [jdk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) `Files`

```
public static Path move​(Path source,
                    Path target,
                    CopyOption... options)
             throws IOException
```

Here is your code changes by using apache commons

```
 for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            File file1 = (File) iterator.next();
            if (file1.getName().contains("FGA_"))
                  FileUtils.moveFile(file1, new File("destination"));
            else if (file1.getName().contains("UPP_"))
                  FileUtils.moveFile(file1, new File("destination"));
     }
```

Comment: this is not moving the file to the specified destination folder instead it is renaming that file with the name destination. And if the folder already exists then it throws exception @Deadpool

Comment: Have you provided the complete path to move the file? @Dolly

Comment: yes i did .. it was like FileUtils.moveFile(file1, new File("C:\\Users\\Heena_Ansari\\Downloads\\New folder")); @Deadpool

Comment: so what is the output? where is the file name in destination path @Dolly? if not you can also try with `jdk` `Files.move`

Comment: Output is it says 'File with name New folder already present at location'. Instead of folder it is renaming the file with New folder @Deadpool

Comment: it should be like this i believe `FileUtils.moveFile(file1, new File("C:\\Users\\Heena_Ansari\\Downloads\\New folder\\destFile.txt"));` @Dolly

Comment: But as we are applying if condition to check if the file name contains either FGA_ or UPP_ then move it to new folder. I don't want to rename it but move with exact name in New folder @Deadpool

Comment: the do like this `FileUtils.moveFile(file1, new File("C:\\Users\\Heena_Ansari\\Downloads\\New folder\\"+file1.getName()));` @Dolly